# Update application layout icon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my application controller I have a method which I use to set notifications and the notifications icon on the application layout menu. I run this method with before_action:

```
def set_notifications
  if user_signed_in?
    @notifications = Notification.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @notifications.each do |n|
      if n.read == false
        return @icon_path = 'notification-alert-icon'
      end
    end
    @icon_path = 'notification-icon'
  end
end
```

This works fine as I get the correct notification icon when I have unread notifications:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%= image_tag(@icon_path) %></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% if @notifications == 0 %>
      <li class="text-center" style="color:white;">Você ainda não tem notificações</li>
    <% else %>
      <% @notifications.each do |n| %>
        <li><%= link_to n.question.title, question_path(n.question), class: 'text-center' %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Ver todas as notificações', "#" %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

When the user clicks the notification icon, then clicks the question he was notified on, the questions_controller marks that notification as read (inside the show action):

```
notifications = Notification.where(question_id: question.id) if Notification.exists?(question_id: question.id)
if notifications
  notifications.each do |notification|
    if notification.user_id == current_user.id
      notification.read = true
      notification.save
    end
  end
end
```

What I haven't been able to do is: how do I update the @notifications object and the notification icon on the application layout after marking the notification as read? I know I can call the method set_notifications but that alone won't reload application layout and change the icon right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code runs to completion before the view renders, so you can do whatever it takes to get things set up prior to the rendering phase. You're free to change variables like `@icon_path` any number of times prior to that phase, the last value set is the one that's used.

If you need to disable the icon in the view after the HTML has been sent to the browser you'll need to use JavaScript to toggle it off.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer me! the very first time I access the page, application controller runs and renders the application layout right? then when I click any link and go to another controller/action, that doesn't mean that application controller will run again and render the application layout again, does it? when I click the link and rails runs questions_controller#show, is it possible reload the entire layout including application layout rather then show.html.erb alone within the application layout loaded previously? or is that what you mean by having to use js?

Comment: The default behaviour for Rails is request/response, like HTTP in general. No state on the Rails side is preserved other than what you persist in the `session`, a database, or files on disk. Each page request starts with a brand new controller instance and a clean slate as far as instance variables go. What do you mean "reload the layout"? Each page request will run from scratch every time.

Comment: So, if I have: <%= link_to 'question', question_path(question) %>,
when I click that link, rails will run a new instance of the application controller and a new instance of the questions controller?

Comment: That's the general principle, yes. Each request is handled in a brand new controller instance. This can seem a bit off if you're used to Android or iOS development where the controller persists for a lot longer, sometimes the life of the entire application process.

Comment: I'm used to mobile development, yes, you hit the nail! It makes a lot of sense now. I just figured my problem is not about reloading the application controller to change the icon. When I mark the notification as read the icon won't change because the HTML has actually ben sent to the browser as you said before, so I need to make it using js - I'll try it! Thanks a lot for your time and patience!

Comment: Well, forget it, all I needed to do was to set @icon_path again on my questions_controller as you also said before. Thank you again!

Comment: The MVC model in Rails isn't like it is on mobile or desktop, so it's a bit of a mind-bending experience to get on track with it. Glad you're on top of it now.